# Resource file is not working properly on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, app-globalresources

I have 2 resource file.. one is default for english and another one is for chinese.
The web app is working fine with VS but when I published it on IIS its not showing chinese language.
I tried other solutions available on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work yet.
I can find resources.dll inside zh(bin) folder on IIS.
Is the error because of there was only one designer file generated that is Resource.designer.cs or something else.
I have made the required changes in Resource File properties like making the class public and build action.
IN web.config I changed

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
```

from false to true.
Please ask if Any other information needed to solve this issue.
Please give me some advice on this.

Comment: Could you please tell me what the application you have used now? MVC or WebForm? Could you please tell me how you modify the client culture? How you test the application and find ou tit doesn't showing chinese language?

Comment: Its a web form. But its ok.. Its working now.. I was playing around with some solutions available. And then I published it on server again. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

When I published it in the beginning the App_GlobalResources didnt get copied on server. I was able to see a resource dll for chiese in bin folder on server but it was of no use I think. doing republishing of website on my server after some changes, got me the desired result. here are the things that I changed -
I went to properties of resource file and changed -

> Build to - Content
>
> Copy to output directory - copy always
>
> custom Tool- PublicGlobalResourceProxyGenerator(made both resource
>   file public)

and then in web.config I changed

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
```

to

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="true" uiCulture="en-US" culture="en-US" />
```

Then I published it and got the chinese option working.